# Configure C++ standard in gradle c++ project?

Tags: c++, gradle, c++17

I have a gradle project defined by the following build script (`build.gradle`):

```
plugins {
    id 'cpp-application'
}

application { 
    targetMachines.add(machines.linux.x86_64)
    targetMachines.add(machines.windows.x86_64)
}
```

This is my directory structure:

```
./src
./src/main
./src/main/cpp
./src/main/cpp/descriptor.cpp
./src/main/cpp/reader_writer.cpp
./src/main/cpp/constant_pool.cpp
./src/main/cpp/unjar.cpp
./src/main/cpp/attribute.cpp
./src/main/cpp/main.cpp
./src/main/cpp/java_serde.cpp
./src/main/headers
./src/main/headers/unjar.h
./src/main/headers/attribute.h
./src/main/headers/constant_pool.h
./src/main/headers/descriptor.h
./src/main/headers/java_serde.h
./src/main/headers/reader_writer.h
./build.gradle
```

Now I want to compile my project, where I am using C++17 features in some source files. I am oblivious as to how I can set the C++ standard version for my gradle build.
How do I tell gradle to compile my code with C++17?

Answer (score 1):

Set the following inside your `application` configuration clause:

```
compilerArgs.add '-std=c++17'
```

If you are targeting multiple platforms, you can set compilerArgs conditionally:

```
compilerArgs.addAll toolChain.map { toolChain ->
        if (toolChain in [ Gcc, Clang ]) {
            return ['-std=++17']
        } else if (toolChain in VisualCpp) {
            return '/std=c++17'
        }
        return []
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

In your gradle script where you kick off cmake, add [cppFlags](https://developer.android.com/reference/tools/gradle-api/7.0/com/android/build/api/dsl/ExternalNativeCmakeOptions#cppflags):

```
cmake {
    cppFlags = "std=c++17"
}
```

Comment: I'm neither using Android build nor am I using CMake. I want to build using only gradle.

Comment: Read up on ExternalNativeBuild -- this is kicked off by gradle and used to compile native (C++) projects.  https://developer.android.com/reference/tools/gradle-api/7.0/com/android/build/api/dsl/ExternalNativeBuild

Answer (score 0):

I hope it helps you:

```
cmake {
cppFlags = "std=c++17"}
```

} <- at 3rd line